# SQL_ID found in dba_hist_sqltext but not in v$sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I had a SQL_ID that i was checking in `v$sql` a few days ago, ga93ryqxj7mcs and bfzp2dt9prncs.

```
select  *
from    v$sql
where   sql_id in ('ga93ryqxj7mcs', 'bfzp2dt9prncs')
```

However, when i queried it today, it's gone. i checked `dba_hist_sqltext` and it's still there:

```
select  *
from    dba_hist_sqltext
where   sql_id in ('ga93ryqxj7mcs', 'bfzp2dt9prncs');
```

It's also in `dba_hist_sqlstat`.
But i'd like to know the PROGRAM_ID of those 2 SQL_IDs, any other views I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’ve purchased the diagnostics pack licence (which you should have if you’re querying dba_hist).

Have a look at `dba_hist_active_sess_history`, if the execution was sampled (which is likely if it’s in dba_hist_sql%) then the `PLSQL_OBJECT_ID` and `PLSQL_SUBPROGRAM_ID` columns will be useful, you can turn the subprogram_id into a procedure within a package using `dba_procedures`. The dba_hist_active_sess_history view can have a lot of data in it so expect a query to take a while. If you know when the executions happened, then lookup the snapshot rows on dba_hist_snapshot and use the snap_id and dbid values as filters on your dba_hist_active_sess_history queries - this will enable partition pruning on the underlying tables.

Comment: I see 'ga93ryqxj7mcs' and 'bfzp2dt9prncs' in the table dba_hist_active_sess_history but PLSQL_SUBPROGRAM_ID and PLSQL_SUBPROGRAM_ID is NULL in my case. Is this expected?

Comment: Anything in `PLSQL_ENTRY_OBJECT_ID`? Is there a chance it wasn’t called from pl/sql?

Comment: yes there's an entry in PLSQL_ENTRY_OBJECT_ID, but it refers to the Job Scheduler. :(

Comment: By default, dbms_scheduler jobs have an `action` of the job name, you can then look up the call in `dba_scheduler_jobs`. I wonder if it’s just running an anonymous block.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Oracle EBS, then you can use the [DBA AWR SQL Performance Summary](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/dba-awr-sql-performance-summary/) blitz report query for this purpose. It shows the top sql_ids, their originating package names, code lines, EBS concurrent program names and much more.